# Google Cloud Vision Api Error

Tags: api, cloud, vision, google-vision

I have a problem with the Google Cloud Vision Api. When I'm trying to send a request to the api with this url:

https://vision.googleapis.com/v1/images:annotate?key=MyKey

The server replies (Error 404):

> The requested URL /v1/images:annotate?key=MyKey was not found on this 
>   server. That’s all we know.

How can I fix this? I tried to do with an ajax request and via browser too.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Maybe `MyKey` should be your API key?

Comment: Of course, but I didn´t want to put it here openly

Comment: Well, the error message is clear : your API key is not found on the server, I'm not a Google Cloud Vision Api user but try to check if there is a delay between your registration and the key activation, maybe your key is no more valid, mabe there is a typo in your key when you write it...

Comment: The problem is that if you try to use the url (https://vision.googleapis.com/v1/images:annotate) without the key, the server should reply you with something, but it replies the same error...so it's like the server doesn´t work or I don´t know..

Comment: @MrSer am facing same problem how you managed it

Answer (score 1):

You should pass the key in the Authorization header not as query parameter.
Check it here: https://cloud.google.com/vision/docs/quickstart-cli